# How to best join these 2 queries

Tags: mysql

I have the following 2 queries and want to join them on store_id to get the # of stores that sell a dell product in a particular post code zone, whether the store is open, the total number of reviews this store had and the average rating of the reviews

```
SELECT s.* , sh . * , d . * , pd . *, 
CASE
  When (holiday = "Y") THEN "Holiday"
END AS open_status
FROM delivery d, products_description pd, store s, store_hours sh 
WHERE d.deliver_to_postcode =5140 
AND d.store_id = pd.store_id 
AND (pd.products_name like '%dell%' or pd.products_description like '%dell%') 
AND pd.store_id = s.store_id 
AND s.store_id = sh.store_id 
AND sh.weekday = dayname( curdate( ) ) 
GROUP BY  d.store_id'


'SELECT store_id, count( * ) AS  reviews, avg( reviews_rating ) AS  rating 
FROM reviews
WHERE  reviews_status =1'


Total stores  | store_id  | store_name  | Postcode | reviews | rating      | open_status
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2             |   1       | store 1     | 5140     |   3     |   2 star    | Holiday
2             |   2       | store 2     | 5140     |   1     |   2 star    | Holiday
```

How can I join these 2 queries to give the result above?

I have added the DB tables

```
Delivery

Store_id |   postcode
--------------------------
1        |  5140
1        |  5200
2        |  5140


Product description

Store_id | product_name
------------------------
1        | pc dell
1        | pc ibm
2        | screen dell


Store

Store_id | Name
-------------------
1        | Store 1
2        | Store 2


Store hours

Store_id | Holiday
-------------------
1        | N
2        | N


Reviews

Store_id | Product  | Review    | review rating
------------------------------------------------
1        | 1        | review 1  |   3 star
1        | 1        | review 2  |   3 star
1        | 2        | review 1  |   3 star
2        | 1        | review 1  |   2 star
```

I have added the DB SQL

--

### -- Table structure for table `delivery`

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `delivery` (
   `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `deliver_to_postcode` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`,`deliver_to_postcode`)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `products_description`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_description` (
    `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `products_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `products_short_description` text,
    `products_description` text,
    `products_keyword` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
    `products_tags` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `products_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `products_friendly_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `products_page_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `products_meta_keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `products_meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `products_viewed` int(5) DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`,`products_id`,`language_id`),
     KEY `products_name` (`products_name`),
     KEY `products_description_keyword` (`products_keyword`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `store`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store` (
   `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   `store_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`),
   KEY `customer_id` (`customer_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `store_hours`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `store_hours` (
    `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `weekday` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `holiday` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    KEY `store_id` (`store_id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

--

### -- Table structure for table `reviews`

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reviews` (
    `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `reviews_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `customers_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `reviews_rating` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `languages_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `reviews_text` text NOT NULL,
    `date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `reviews_read` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `reviews_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`,`reviews_id`)
  ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: You might want to make a SQLFiddle, because there is a whole structure that we don't know.

Comment: post table create code

Comment: also, you are using deprecated join syntax, you might want to update it to make it readable

Comment: And don't use (implicit/) comma join syntax. It's difficult to read and manioulate. Use (explicit) JOIN syntax instead.

Comment: 1 - What is a SQLFiddle  2 - Added table create code  3 - what do you mean I posted 2 select statements?  4 - what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a solution here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/691a1/8

There are some notes on this solution:

- I believe your queries above are "wrong".  The first query has a `GROUP BY`, and not aggregate functions.  Your 2nd query has aggregate functions, yet no `GROUP BY` line.  I moved the `GROUP BY` clause to the second query.
- Use of the asterisks are overkill.  SQLFiddle does **not** list duplicate columns. Thus, store_id is only listed once.
- I changed your first query from using implicit (theta style) joins to explicit (ANSI style) joins.

Here is the query

```
SELECT tmp.*, s.* , sh.* , d.* , pd.*, 
  CASE
    When (holiday = "Y") THEN "Holiday"
  END AS open_status
FROM delivery d
JOIN  products_description pd
  ON d.store_id = pd.store_id
JOIN store s
  ON pd.store_id = s.store_id
JOIN store_hours sh 
  ON s.store_id = sh.store_id
JOIN (
    SELECT store_id, count(*) AS  reviews, avg(reviews_rating) AS  rating 
    FROM reviews
    WHERE  reviews_status =1
    GROUP BY store_id) AS tmp
  ON tmp.store_id = s.store_id
WHERE d.deliver_to_postcode =5140 
  AND (pd.products_name like '%dell%' or pd.products_description like '%dell%') 
  AND sh.weekday = dayname( curdate( ) )
```

Comment: Thank you. The query works fine if I add GROUP BY d.store_id at the end of the query. Without it the query returns a row for each product. Is this the best way of doing it or can I use something like a distinct or limit 1 statement on the select (pd.products_name like '%dell%' or pd.products_description like '%dell%') statement?

Comment: Don't use `GROUP BY` unless you have aggregate functions.  Use `DISTINCT` in the SELECT clause if you have duplicate "records" being returned.

Comment: @user2882043 - In the SQLFiddle example, I can see that the same product_id is listed twice, but there are different store_id, differing reviews.  If you don't need them, get rid of them from the output.  If you need them, then by using `GROUP BY` you don't get their unique values (and to complicate matters, MySQL will 'randomly' choose a value)

Comment: Thanks. I have added a distinct and a left join and it works fine now. Result is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/691a1/14

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
    count(s.store_id) count,
    s.*,
    sh.*,
    ( SELECT count(*)
      FROM reviews r
      WHERE r.reviews_status = 1 AND r.store_id = s.store_dd ) reviews
FROM store s
JOIN delivery d ON s.store_id = d.store_id
JOIN products_description pd ON pd.store_id = d.store_id
JOIN store_hours sh ON sh.store_id = d.store_id
WHERE
    d.deliver_to_postcode = 5140 AND
    sh.weekday = dayname(curdate()) AND
    (pd.products_name LIKE '%dell%' OR pd.products_description LIKE '%dell%')
GROUP BY s.store_id
```

I cannot do more for you, cause I dont have your DB model/structure

Comment: This solution multiplies all the reviews by the number of products it finds.

Comment: I have edited my query, I think it will be really slow, but check if it does what you need, we can then play with optimalisation

Comment: Nearly there. However the count(s.store_id) count returns the # of product descriptions found instead of the total # of stores with the product. i.e if 5 stores sell dell products the total # of stores should be 5. Also I can not get the average review rating as the 2nd select allows only 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

To answer part of your question - this is the format of the syntax to follow in order to join your two queries - fill in your SQL statements in the **[[query place holders]]**

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
  [[query1]]
  ) AS q1
JOIN (
   [[query2]]
  ) AS q2
  ON q1.store_id = q2.store_id
```

Note: My use of the asterisk was for demonstration purposes, please don't put that into production.  Also, I don't see why your first query uses the GROUP BY - there are no aggregate functions.

Comment: This solution does not work due to the count(*) and avg(rating) in the 2nd query.  The group by in the 1st query is to get only 1 product per store to avoid getting all the reviews multiplied by the # of products

Comment: @user2882043 - You need to load a SQLFiddle if you want help.

Comment: @user2882043 - It is a web based SQL server.  Go to sqlfiddle.com, load up your schema and sample data.  Then copy the url and share it via this post.  Anyone who wants to answer, can go to that link and try out their code